# csrf verification failed even after using csrf_exempt

Tags: django-views, django-csrf

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

This error happens even after using csrf_exempt in the views.py page .How to resolve this issue?
[image: index.html]
[image: views.py]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8tGL.png

Answer (score 0):

Django handles csrf automatically so not need to exempt for your code just add csrf template tag in HTML Template like this...

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
</form>
```

and remove @csrf_exempt decorator which is on top of add_item

NOTE:- When you send POST request then require to add csrf token in html post form